# Issue while using Multiple KafkaProducerMessageHandler with spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka, mapr-streams

This is the extension of the post [MaprStream with spring integration Kafka Producer issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864698/replaying-maprstream-messages)

I am facing issues with multiple KafkaProducerMessageHandlers when tried to achieve the sync property while publishing messages to maprstream

```
@Autowired
Qualifier("abcHandler.handler")
private KafkaProducerMessageHandler abcHandler;

@Autowired
Qualifier("xyzHandler.handler")
private KafkaProducerMessageHandler xyzHandler;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.abcHandler.setSync(true);
    this.xyzHandler.setSync(true);
}
```

Bean configuration:

```
<int:chain input-channel="inputToKafka"> 
    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter 
            id="abcHandler" 
            kafka-template="template" 
            topic="${maprstream.stream.topicname}" > 
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter> 
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="inputToKafka1"> 
    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter 
            id="xyzHandler" 
            kafka-template="template1" 
            topic="${maprstream.stream.topicname1}" > 
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter> 
</int:chain>
```

I am getting the below exception while trying to load the beans.

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
>   Error creating bean with name 'maprStreamProducerHandlerSync': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'abcHandler'; 
>   nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
>   'org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
>   Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), 
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=abcHandler.handler)}

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have these single components within `<chain/>`s? Chains are usually used for grouping multiple elements.

See [the documentation about chains](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#chain); scroll down to **'id' Attribute`**.

```
<int:chain id="chain1" input-channel="inputToKafka"> 
    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter 
            id="abcHandler" 
            kafka-template="template" 
            topic="${maprstream.stream.topicname}" > 
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter> 
</int:chain>
```

Components within chains get composite bean names. in this case it would be `chain1$child.abcHandler.handler`. When auto wiring, you would need to use this value in a `@Qualifier` when you have more than one adapter.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the update. Yes, I made the changes as below <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter 
            id="abcHandler" 
   channel="inputToKafka"
            kafka-template="template" 
            topic="${maprstream.stream.topicname}" > 
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>   and it worked..!!